# Using unicorn for manual deployment on Dev/QA environments

Tags: unicorn, deployment

I am trying do manually deploy unicorn serialized yml files into my QA server. But, I am getting exception even while loading the Sitecore instance.

I have copied all the feature/foundation/project folders, except the code folders inside them. Hence, all the folders have only serialization folder. The same path is mentioned in the source path for unicorn as. Am I missing any thing here?

Please help me in understanding how to manually deploy yml files.

Following is the exception:

```
[IOException: The device is not ready.]   
System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath) +1093    System.IO.Directory.InternalCreateDirectory(String fullPath, String path, Object dirSecurityObj, Boolean checkHost) +1258   
System.IO.Directory.InternalCreateDirectoryHelper(String path, Boolean checkHost) +64   
Rainbow.Storage.SerializationFileSystemDataStore.InitializeRootPath(String rootPath) +346   
Rainbow.Storage.SerializationFileSystemDataStore..ctor(String physicalRootPath, Boolean useDataCache, ITreeRootFactory rootFactory, ISerializationFormatter formatter) +233    
lambda_method(Closure, Object[] ) +246
Configy.Containers.MicroContainer.Activate(Type type, KeyValuePair2[] unmappedConstructorParameters) +819   
Unicorn.Configuration.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<RegisterConfigTypeInterface>b__3() +38
System.Lazy1.CreateValue() +242    
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +31   
System.Lazy1.get_Value() +14803913   
Unicorn.Data.ConfigurationDataStore.RegisterForChanges(Action2 actionOnChange) +19   
Unicorn.Data.DataProvider.UnicornDataProvider..ctor(ITargetDataStore targetDataStore, ISourceDataStore sourceDataStore, IPredicate predicate, IFieldFilter fieldFilter, IUnicornDataProviderLogger logger, IUnicornDataProviderConfiguration dataProviderConfiguration, ISyncConfiguration syncConfiguration, PredicateRootPathResolver rootPathResolver) +546    
lambda_method(Closure , Object[] ) +402   
Configy.Containers.MicroContainer.Activate(Type type, KeyValuePair2[] unmappedConstructorParameters) +819   
Configy.Containers.MicroContainer.Resolve() +118   
System.Linq.WhereSelectArrayIterator2.MoveNext() +75   
System.Linq.Buffer1..ctor(IEnumerable1 source) +162   
System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray(IEnumerable`1 source) +106   
Unicorn.Data.DataProvider.UnicornSqlServerDataProvider..ctor(String connectionString) +219
```

Comment: your `targetDataStore` is pointing to a drive that does not exist in your target environment. Make sure to update this setting across environments.

Comment: Also make sure you give the App Pool user of your site read/write permissions to the serialization folder.

Answer (score 2):

Ran into this issue deploying Habitat to Azure VM. Here is quick solution based on [Mark Cassidy](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/users/73/mark-cassidy)'s response.

Culprit is the below file. Your file location may be different. but I guess you got the location we are pointing to.

```
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\HabitatCM\Website\App_Config\Include\Project\z.Habitat.DevSettings.config
```

In this file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <sc.variable name="sourceFolder" value="E:\\Projects\\Habitat\\src" />
```

Verify the `sourceFolder` value. This may be pointing to a drive which may not be existing. As this is what happened in my case.

Once I changed it to `C:\Habitat` I am able to see the Sitecore login page.

Hope this helps.